# Cannot modify set in cython

Tags: python, c++, set, cython

I want to decalare a set of unsigned ints in c++, and modify it within Python:

```python
%load_ext Cython
%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython 
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.set cimport set as cpp_set
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

def modify_test_data():
    cdef (cpp_set[int])* s = new cpp_set[int]()
    print deref(s), type(deref(s))
    deref(s).add(1)
    print deref(s)

modify_test_data()
```

Output:

```python
set([]) <type 'set'>
set([]) # here i would expect 'set([1])'
```

I am not sure if I need the deref stuff, but without it, the types were not matching. Can somebody explain how I can do this in a clean/elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, you're conflating Python's `set` with C++'s [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). The latter's method is `insert`, not `add` (as is the former's).

If you change the relevant line to:

```
deref(s).insert(1)
```

the output becomes:

```
set([]) <type 'set'>
set([1])
```

Comment: Hm, that was easy :) Thank you!